# Which post-hoc comparison to use and why

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, post-hoc, kruskal-wallis-test

**Hopefully this is now a much clearer picture of the question I want to answer:**

For each of 60 different plans I ran 35 simulation replications of my Agent Based Model (ABM) simulation.  Then for each simulation replication of each plan, I generated a score ($\geq0$), so that I ended up with 35 scores for each of the 60 plans.  I now want to find the best plan which I define as the plan with the smallest mean score.

Of course I can compute the mean score for each one of the 60 plans, and I can rank each plan according to the mean score.  At this point how do I test whether the 1st ranked mean score is statistically significantly different to the 2nd ranked score.  And if I find it is not, how do I test whether the first two ranked mean scores are statistically significantly different to the 3rd ranked score, and so forth.  Eventually I would like to end up with a set of plans (although the set can contain only one plan) for which I can state that the set of plans are equally best (as far as being statistically significantly the same).

**This is what I was considering doing:**

For each plan I compute the mean score and then select the 5 plans with the 5 smallest scores.  I then use the [Kruskal-Wallis H-Test](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.kruskal.html#scipy-stats-kruskal) to determine if any of the 5 means are significantly different (since my samples do not satisfy the normality or homoscedasticity assumptions of [ANOVA](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html#scipy-stats-f-oneway)).

If the p-value returned by the test is less than my significance level $\alpha$ then I know that at least one of the means is different and want to test for which one this is (are).  At this point I need to use a post-hoc comparison test but am unsure as to which one I should use and why.

Comment: I'll just suggest searching for "ranking and selection" as the term that applies to this type of problem.

Comment: You seem to be throwing away the information needed to help solve your problem: by reducing each set of 35 replicates to a single score, you have eliminated all identifiable information about variation within the simulations. That leaves you powerless to attribute variations between the scores to anything but chance. As such, you cannot really conclude anything. Have you considered analyzing all $60\times 35$ values that you obtained, perhaps with an ANOVA, in order to assess the differences?

Comment: PS I'll add that I don't see any reason at all to do the ANOVA (or K-W test). It's not necessary if your goal is just ranking the means (or medians?), and moreover it's pretty strange to do an ANOVA (or K-W) after using the data to select the treatments to include.

Comment: @whuber For each of the 60 plans I have 35 scores, one score per replication.  I then want to see which plan has the (statistically significantly) smallest mean score.  Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @RussLenth My only objective is to come up with the "best" plan, where best is defined as the plan with the smallest mean score.  I can order the mean scores in ascending order, sure, however how can I tell that the 1st ranked mean score is statistically significantly different from the 2nd ranked mean score?

Comment: @Russ You might want to expand a little on how you are interpreting this question.  Your comments suggest you could be thinking of it differently than some other readers. For instance, in light of the OP's latest comment, would you object to, say, a Tukey HSD test?  Because it is based on an ANOVA, it sounds like you would, but why?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is not explained well enough. You want a "significant" score. What is the null hypothesis? What alternative hypothesis are you proposing? What decision will you make with that conclusion? And backing up, what plans are you talking about? And why any statistical calculations. Just take the one with the smallest (best) score?

Comment: Answering @whuber... The Tukey HSD is *not* based on ANOVA, it relies only on the Studentized range distribution for its validity. The ANOVA is the most convenient way to get the MSE, but requiring a significant $F$ as a prerequisite for using the HSD makes it unnecessarily conservative. I think ANOVA is way over-used and widely misunderstood. It doesn't really answer very many important questions, especially for fixed effects.

Comment: Further comments more on this application re the HSD. The HSD is not the right choice here because you only need to compare the best plan with each of the others. For the normal-theory method, look at page 104 of Oehlert's book - http://users.stat.umn.edu/~gary/Book.html - which is a free download. The procedure is to use Dunnett one-sided critical values to compare the best with each of the others.

Comment: @Russ It sounds like you conceive of ANOVA as consisting of a lot more analysis and testing than either I or, say, the Wikipedia entry on HSD would. Anyway, I do not understand your claim that only the "best plan" need be compared with the others. Which one, exactly, is the "best" given that all are subject to variation? Not necessarily the one whose mean score is closest to zero! When I contemplate the extreme case of no real differences among plans--so that all differences are due to random variation--it seems evident that in principle many more comparisons are needed than you intimate.

Comment: @whuber Given the edited version of my question up top, is there a course of analysis you would suggest taking?

Comment: I'll stick by the Dunnett-like procedure. Convert each set of data to ranks (note the KW test is essentially an ANOVA on ranks). Identify the plan with the lowest mean rank, and compare that mean with the others using the one-sided Dunnett critical values.